# How does js.erb work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-ajax, erb

Lately i have run into a few applications that are using `js.erb` and i am not really sure how to use it ...here is the code below. Can someone help me understand how this works?

in the `routes.rb` file

```
map.resources :player_emails
```

my controller `player_emails_controller.rb` in the create action

```
def create
 @player_email = PlayerEmail.create(params[:player_email])
 if @player_email.save
  @response_txt = "The player has been emailed."
  PlayerEmailsMailer.deliver_pattern_email(@something, @player_email, request.host_with_port)
  @error = false
 else
  @error = true
  @response_txt = "Please make sure you entered your name and a valid email address."
 end
end
```

then i have the file `player_emails/create.js.erb`

```
$('#player_email_ind').hide();
$('#player_email_submit').show();
$('#player_response_msg').html("<%= escape_javascript @response_txt %>").fadeIn();
<% unless @error %>
$('#player_email_form')[0].reset();
<% end %>
```

i know what the jquery is going but i dont know how this is doing the `ajax` call. Does it just automatically do an `ajax` call when there is a `js.erb`...can someone explain the way this works and why i dont need a respond_to in the controller action telling it this is `format.js`

Comment: i am just curious if there is a tutorial for writing .js.erb out there ...

Answer (score 7):

If a js (ajax) request is made it will respond by rendering the js.erb file and viceversa.

This is the default behaviour that is being performed:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{
      render :template => 'create.js.erb'
    }
    format.html{
      render :template => 'create.html.erb'
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

When the form is submitted, it does a POST to `/player_emails`. The resource declaration in `routes.rb` ensures the request is handled by `PlayerEmailsController#create`.

The controller is responsible for handling each format it receives. In the case of an AJAX call, the format is 'js', and is set by explicitly adding the format string to the end of the URL (`/player_emails.js`) or (more likely) by deducing the format from the request header.

In your case, the `create` action does not expect anything other than AJAX, so it takes a shortcut and omits the `respond_to` and `format` blocks. The controller has already figured out that the format is 'js', so when `create` is complete it takes the default action of rendering the appropriate template for the format (`create.js.erb`).

Answer (score 3):

Does your form submit button have a `:remote => true` on it? If so, there might be some JavaScript in `rails.js` or `application.js` that automatically submits via AJAX. Bottom line is, there has to be some JavaScript somewhere that is making an AJAX call and asking for a js or JSON response, otherwise it would be an html request.

As for why you don't need a `respond_to` block, I'm not entirely sure. Maybe since the call is always being made by AJAX and there is a js.erb template available, it just does its thing without complaining. Is there an html.erb template at all? If not, try doing a regular form submit and see if it complains.