# Update Ruby on Rails partial with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've built a fav icon that works like a Facebook like/unlike button, and I'm trying to update it via Ajax but can't seem to get it working. I think I'm missing something simple.

events_controller.rb

```
def fav
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  current_user.toggle_flag(@event, :fav) #events_helper.rb 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

events_helper.rb

```
def toggle_fav(event, user)
  if user_signed_in? #change icon from heart to empty heart and vice-versa
    link_to user.flagged?(event, :fav) ? #if the event is flagged
      content_tag(:span, " ", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart") : #show full heart
      content_tag(:span, " ", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"), #else show empty heart
      fav_event_path(event), #path that changes the state of the heart
      :remote => true
    else
      link_to content_tag(:span, " ", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"), fav_event_path(event) #prompt user to sign in
  end
end
```

Events/index.html.erb

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <%= render 'each_event', :event => event %>
<% end %>
```

_each_event.html.erb (relevant info only)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="event-div">
    <div class="event-details">
      <ul><li class="fav-li"><%= render 'fav_li', :event => event %></li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_fav_li.html.erb

```
<%= toggle_fav(event, current_user) %>
```

fav.js.erb

```
$('.fav-li').html('<%=j render 'events/fav_li', :event => event, :layout => false %>');
```

I followed this tutorial to make the like button: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG-kCSx0taU
And am using the make_flaggable gem.

Right now when I update the button it directs me to `http://localhost:3000/events/23/fav` but that template doesn't exist (and shouldn't). The events are displayed on the event index page after going through the index filters. There are multiple events on a single page.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is doing `format.js` in the `respond_to` block. It's expecting a js template to exist so it can run it as the response. Something like `app/views/events/fav.js.erb`. This file will contain some js code that will update your view with the results of your controller action e.g. update the icon from `glyphicon-heart-empty` to `glyphicon-heart`.

Here's another question/answer discussing js.erb templates: [How does js.erb work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606855/how-does-js-erb-work)

Hope that helps.